# custom Samsung health app issue?

Tags: java, android, sdk

I am developed Custom Samsung Health Application by using Samsung S Health SDK and also they provide beta version "HealthDevApp.apk" file for testing. "HealthDevApp" is working just like a "Samsung Native S Health App" which is preinstall on the Samsung Device s4 and S5.

I able to run my application by connecting with the "HealthDevApp.apk" file but i am not able to connect my application with "Samsung Native S Health App" which preinstall on the device.

Can any one please help me how i connect my application with "Samsung Native S Health App".

Comment: Have you exposed the service? Detailed in the PDF downloaded from here: http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000211L That is how the plugin (your app) gets registered with the preinstalled app. There are other important steps too, so make sure you go through that document.

Comment: Still i am not getting any idea from document that you have given link. Is there needed any permission or any think else. If needed permission, then what permission i will mention there in my manifest? Please help me.

Comment: Permissions are clearly explained in the document. But you have a working example, why not compare your code/manifest to it if you're having trouble following the instructions in the document?

Comment: No one can help beyond that because you haven't provided any information or code. We'd just be guessing what's wrong. I've guessed and asked "Have you exposed the service?" but you didn't reply to that.

Comment: I am working on this issue right now!  The only item the manual says is to remove the metadata around platform_type, but that does not work for me.

Answer (score 8):

Though
you have created an application with Samsung Digital Health SDK, the application can only work with S Health after the application is approved as S Health’s partner apps. To register your application as S Health’s partner app. You can test your application with 
S Health's developer mode.

The 
S Health’s developer mode is not active by default. You can use the developer mode as the following steps.

1)Select the action overflow of S Health on the top-right side.

2)Find Settings > About S Health in the action list.

3)Tap the version region quickly for 10 times.

4)If it succeeds, "*(Developer Mode)*" is shown in front of the version and it means the developer mode is activated. Now you can test your application on S Health.